# Is it useful remove declared script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

When i used to write very long declare script tag(ex. base64 encoded image), I had a question.

If the script tag remains after the variable is declared(or executed), does not have an bad effect on memory (or overall performance)?

```html
<div id="ex">
  <script>
    window.something.obj = {
                 // blah blah...
                };
    
    window.something.image = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';
  </script>
</div>

<script>
  (function () {
    document.querySelector('#ex').innerHTML = '';
  })();
</script>
```

So I wrote this code. Could this code help performance?

Comment: If your asking whether its worth removing a script thats already been run during the page loading and won't run again, no, you will just be creating something to run on something that isn't and or won't run again.

Comment: @akaBase Yes. I wonder if that long statement already executed affects the performance of the browser.

Comment: No, it will only have an effect while the page is loading and its being run.

Comment: The copy in the original HTML source code remains of course intact and I presume that removing the corresponding data structure in the DOM tree is not guaranteed to trigger garbage collection. In order to really know if it makes any difference you'd really need to so some serious benchmark in different runtimes (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge... and Windows, Linux, Android, iOS...) but I suspect the potential performance benefit is tiny unless you're seriously abusing inline blobs (in which case you'd need to address the problem in a different way).